# Combining ndb.Tasklets with memcache reads

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Say I want to read the following object structure, and want to parallelize the reads as much as possible:

```
root_object --> ShardCounter
            |
             -> SubObject1 (1..N)
            |
             -> SubObject2 (1..N) --> ShardCounter
                                  |
                                   -> SubObject3 (1..N)
```

1) Is it meaningful to interact with memcache and/or store to fetch the ShardCounters from within the tasklets? As far as I can see memcache does not have a `get_async`, so I'm a bit unsure about whether or not this would parallelize well?

2) In the tasklet that produces the results for `SubObject2`, would I use the `iter.has_next_async()` pattern or would I call `fecth_async().map(...)` to retrieve the `SubObject3`'s, or something different entirely (another tasklet, for example)?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although async functions for memcache aren't defined at the top level, the Client class has async functions, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass), which you can use with NDB and tasklets. NDB won't be able to combine multiple async get operations into one multi get, though, so depending on what you're doing, it may be more efficient to do a `get_multi` instead. Edit: NDB does have a Memcache interface - see Guido's answer for details.

For your second question, you'll have to elaborate a bit on what you're doing with the results and why, and what you see the alternatives as. If all you need to do is fetch all the async results, you can just yield them all in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you are a great help!

Answer (score 7):

NDB *does* have auto-batching asynchronous memcache apis, on the Context object.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/contextclass .